TeXShop key shortcut for "Comment"
For years I have used cmd{ to comment highlighted text in TeXShop.  Today I turned on my Mac and discovered that cmd{ has been replaced by cmd/.  How do I change it back?

I'm having the same issue. Recently updated to Sequoia 15.0; running TeXShop 5.44

Richard Koch replied that TeXShop v5.45 will have a fix.  Meantime, Herb Schulz describes a manual correction in the TeXShop mailing list at TUG.org

I‘m relieved to know it‘s not something I did.  Herb‘s suggestion is to use the Mac‘s own key shortcut facility which allows one to assign shortcuts for individual apps.  I did this and it works just fine.  Tnx.
